# Why does C++11 allow abstract final classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the following code compile? I'm using Visual Studio; I'm not sure if it's just not standard-compliant, or if there are good reasons for allowing this, or if it's just an oversight in the language.

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

// since this class is final and abstract, it can never be
// instantiated - why isn't its very declaration an error?
struct Derived final : Base {};

int main() {
  //Derived derived; // this IS an error, but relies on someone trying
                     // to instantiate the class, and the error is at the site
                     // of instantiation, not the class itself
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is because `static` members are still relevant.

Comment: To elaborate: because `Derived`'s `static` members and `friend`s can access `Base`'s `protected` members, so `Derived` isn't necessarily completely useless.

Comment: Does it have to be explicitly forbidden just because it isn't useful?

Comment: @sth Nope - "It's not useful, but there's no other reason to forbid it" could be a valid answer. I've come to expect though that very smart people come up with these things and have good reasons for making things forbidden/allowed - there seem to be very few things like this that are allowed but are completely useless in all circumstances.

Comment: I'd point out, that nothing stops one from using `Derived` in some kind of perverse MPL construct. In fact, one could have a huge inheritance tree of things branching off of `Base` that end in `final` leaves as terminals that are used merely for their types. Just because I have no desire to ever code like that doesn't mean someone won't.

Comment: @Karu: Not really... `Derived` can only access protected members on an object of type `Derived`, which can't exist.

Comment: @Karu, this gives a warning under clang: "abstract class is marked 'final'": http://i.imgur.com/KySz6Go.png

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah. To clarify I was thinking about protected static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's no good reason to forbid it. It doesn't seem very useful, but if you want a struct that cannot be instantiated but still offers static member functions, this is one way to accomplish that. (A private constructor is probably a better way to achieve this end.)

Leave it to Java and friends to outlaw this sort of thing: [Why is public abstract final class syntactically invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149546)