# Why is public abstract final class syntactically invalid?

Tags: java

I have a class `foo` that is no more than a placeholder for a few `static` functions and variables. A bit like a `namespace` in C++.

Creating an instance of `foo` and inheriting from `foo` are therefore meaningless.

So I'm tempted to write `public abstract final class foo`. But Java dislikes that. I can do it in C++ with a pure virtual function and `final`, but why can't I do the equivalent in Java? What's so wrong with my design?

**Update:**
I'm getting heavily downvoted on this (-4 at the time of writing) so I obviously haven't been clear enough. Here's the specific use case. It's a load of severity level codes for error logging that's used in a JNI and supporting C library:

```
public abstract class Severity
{ 
    public static final int TRACE = 0x00000001;

    public static final int INFORMATION = 0x00000002;

    public static final int WARNING = 0x00000003;

    public static final int ERROR = 0x00000004;

    public static final int CRITICAL_ERROR = 0x00000005;

    public static final int OFF = 0x00000006;
}
```

So it's almost like an enumerator but the JNI and C library restrictions mean that would be suboptimal. Making this `abstract` **and** `final` seems perfectly reasonable to me, and, as I've said, the equivalent is permissible in C++.

Comment: From what I understand, that should be a `public static class` and you methods should be `static`. Also add a private constructor. Utlity class.

Comment: Because `abstract` and `final` are mutually exclusive. Declaring a class as `abstract` is a signifier that you *intend for the class to be extended*. Declaring it `final` signifies *you cannot extend this class*.

Comment: It's a good question. People are too quick to down vote. Other languages have ways to declare a class cannot be instantiated nor extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use empty enum instead class

```
public enum Severity
{ ;
    public static final int TRACE = 0x00000001;

    public static final int INFORMATION = 0x00000002;

    public static final int WARNING = 0x00000003;

    public static final int ERROR = 0x00000004;

    public static final int CRITICAL_ERROR = 0x00000005;

    public static final int OFF = 0x00000006;
}
```

you cant instantiate enum, you can't extend enum. hence it gives you all what you want

Comment: Let me try this. I don't *think* it messes up the JNI.

Comment: **THIS IS ABSOLUTELY BRILLIANT** What does the `;` do?

Comment: @P45Imminent `;` is used  to separate enum values from enum members. what you are doing here is, you create enum without values with some static fields.

Comment: @P45Imminent Usually the first thing in an enum is the list of enum elements, comma separated and terminated by a semicolon. The semicolon here is terminating the (non-existant) list of enum elements, leaving you with an empty enum.

Comment: @P45Imminent Your reason for disliking the private constructor answer was that it can be circumvented with reflection, but you can use reflection to instantiate this `enum` version too.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm not so sure, as far as i remember, you will get `IllegalArgumentException: Cannot reflectively create enum objects`

Comment: @user902383 Oh really? I'm completely wrong then. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I just play around, and Confirm that, but maybe there is a trick so cant tell in 100%

Answer (score 6):

Because `abstract` says that is has some unimplemented methods and `final` states that it cannot be inherited from. That means this class can never be useful. If your class does not contain any instance methods, just make it `final` and you're done :). No need to mark it `abstract` because it isn't. You probably also want to make the constructor `private` so no one can instantiate it.

See for example the [JLS 8.1.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1):

> 8.1.1.1. abstract Classes
>
> An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be considered incomplete.
>
> [...]

and  [JLS 8.1.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)

> 8.1.1.2. final Classes
>
> [...]
>
> It is a compile-time error if a class is declared both final and abstract, because the implementation of such a class could never be completed (§8.1.1.1).

Comment: Not at all. I can do it in C++ and it *would* be useful in my case. Marking a constructor private is a contrivance and it can be circumvented with reflection.

Comment: Indeed but I'm mentioning C++ to establish that there is nothing fundamentally wrong or contradictory with what I want to do.

Comment: the semantics of `abstract` are most likely different in C++ and Java.

Comment: Yes you're correct. C++ doesn't actually have `abstract`: you make a class `abstract` by having at least one pure virtual function, that is, a function without a definition. But the principal, as far as I can see, is the same.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, if you want to write a class that can neither be instantiated nor extended, use a `private` constructor

```
private MyClass() {}
```

Arguably there should be a way of specifying this in the class declaration, but there isn't.

Comment: This is the correct idiom to define a class that cannot be instantiated in Java. Both `abstract` and `enum` have different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

In a one liner when you say a class as final then it means that class can't be extended, an abstract class needs to be extended. So its a logical contradiction.

**EDIT:**

The edit seems fine and your code looks good. You cannot instantiate Severity because of it abstract so you can have the variables as final.

Comment: No it isn't. My specific case is valid.

Comment: @P45Imminent:- Yes I see the edit. Updated my answer.

Comment: But I don't want someone to inherit it and bung in other codes either. I just want a C++ namespace!

Comment: @P45Imminent:- I am not sure what is stopping you from creating an enum?

Answer (score -1):

`abstract` and `final` are mutually-exclusive concepts in Java. When you declare a class to be `abstract`, you are saying "I intend for this class to be subclassed by one or more other classes". When you declare it `final`, you're saying "I intend that this class cannot be extended by any class". As such, an `abstract final` class makes no sense from a Java perspective - so the language doesn't permit you to do it in the first place.

For your specific use-case, why not simply use an `enum`?

```
public enum Severity {
    TRACE,
    INFORMATION,
    WARNING,
    ERROR,
    CRITICAL_ERROR,
    OFF;
}
```

You can always include numeric values for each enum element if you wish.