# C++/CX using abstract + final keywords together

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I'm working on a C++/CX project and just came across the following definition:

```
#pragma once

struct ColorHelper abstract final {
    static COLORREF Lighten(COLORREF color, int amount);
    static COLORREF Darken(COLORREF color, int amount);
    static bool IsSystemThemeDark();
};
```

I'm a bit confused. The **abstract** keyword tells me that I cannot instatiate this class but the **final** keyword says that I **cannot** derive from it, so what gives? Is this supposed to be like a namespace? Or maybe something like a static class in C#?

Comment: This is not specific to C++/CX [Why does C++11 allow abstract final classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806339/why-does-c11-allow-abstract-final-classes)

Comment: @SimonMourier well, the  keyword abstract is from C++/CX. Thanks fors linking that question

Comment: `abstract` is actually a valid keyword in standard C++ with MSVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/abstract-cpp-component-extensions

Comment: @SimonMourier yeye, but, regarding this construct, I think it's safe to say this could easily be replaced by a namespace right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **abstract** keyword tells me that I cannot instatiate this class but the **final** keyword says that I cannot derive from it, so what gives?

That's correct. The only available operation for this type is accessing its `static` class members.

> Is this supposed to be like a namespace?

Yes, pretty much. If `ColorHelper` was a C++ namespace it would have an identical interface as far as clients are concerned.

So then, why is it not a namespace and rather a type with a somewhat obscure definition?

Because not all programming languages (such as C#) support calling free functions. Since `ColorHelper` is a Windows Runtime type there are restrictions on how it can be modeled to support cross-language interoperability. Specifically, all functions need to be implemented on a type, even when that means introducing a type that can never be instantiated.

In essence, an `abstract final` type with `static` class members exclusively is the moral equivalent of a C++ namespace expressed in a way that makes it accessible across all supported Windows Runtime languages.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you